# Get the data of a table using of two columns only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to the `webDevelopment`.I have searched a lot but I did not get the solution. Here I have a table like -

```
A             B      C      D
FullName     ABC    pqr     xyz
TelephoneNo  123    RST     GHI
```

Here I want to have the data of the table of a specific columns like

```
A and B
```

So, the data should be like -

```
FullName: ABC
```

I want to have the data of rows present in the column A and column B

Html -

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table" id="tableid" contextmenu-container="meta.contextmenu" fixed-header>
            <thead class="text-center text-info">
              <th class="text-center">Annotation</th>
              <th class="text-center">Field</th>
              <th class="text-center">Message</th>
              <th class="text-center">Score</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
              <td class="td-report-field" contentEditable contextmenu-item="report" context-menu="menuOptions">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                      {{ report.attributes.message }}
                    </span>
                <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

what I tries --

```
var oTable = document.getElementById('tableid');
                    //gets rows of table
                    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

                    //loops through rows    
                    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

                    //gets cells of current row  
                    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

                    //gets amount of cells of current row
                    var cellLength = oCells.length;

                    //loops through each cell in current row
                    for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
                            var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
                            alert(cellVal);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Basically you need logic to read a column from table. Please provide HTML markup for your table to help better.

Comment: I don't think you "*have searched a lot*" as you said.

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm giving the answer based on your first half your question with example data.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg0uyc44/)

```js
$('table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).children()[0].innerHTML + ": " + $(this).children()[1].innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>
        B
      </td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fullname</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TelephoneNo</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>GHJ</td>
      <td>TYU</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you go with pure `JavaScript` https://jsfiddle.net/mg0uyc44/1/

```js
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for(var i=0; i<tr.length; i++){
 console.log(tr[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML + ": " + tr[i].childNodes[3].innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>
        B
      </td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fullname</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TelephoneNo</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>GHJ</td>
      <td>TYU</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```